# IIS threads running at 20% utilization infinitely on Kernel32.GetModuleA

Tags: iis-6

We have a recent web application rollout on Windows Server 2003/IIS.  Multiple times a day a thread spawns that will run at 20%-25% utilization. Using process explorer, I see the stack that is posted at the bottom of this message.  I can kill these threads and it does not appear to impact anything.  However, everyday I have to watch the web server and kill them as they arise or the app slows to a crawl.

I need a way to troubleshoot this and determine the source of the problem.  Any ideas?

---

ntkrnlpa.exe+0x8db2e ntkrnlpa.exe+0x29a82 ntkrnlpa.exe+0x331a4 ntkrnlpa.exe+0x2e3c6 ntkrnlpa.exe+0xf6299 ntkrnlpa.exe+0xeede2 ntkrnlpa.exe+0x897cc ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet WS2_32.dll!recv+0x6f AppSvr.dll!DllUnregisterServer+0x652 OLEAUT32.dll!DispCallFunc+0xab OLEAUT32.dll!SafeArrayCopyData+0x397 AppSvr.dll!DllGetClassObject+0xab8 OLEAUT32.dll!DllRegisterServer+0x5bf RPCRT4.dll!NdrAsyncServerCall+0x1e7 RPCRT4.dll!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x82 OLEAUT32.dll!DispGetParam+0x5b6 ole32.dll!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x13d32 ole32.dll!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x13cdf ole32.dll!DcomChannelSetHResult+0xaab ole32.dll!DcomChannelSetHResult+0x495 ole32.dll!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x13fbe ole32.dll!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x13a7d ole32.dll!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x12f64 ole32.dll!CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx+0x9f5 ole32.dll!CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx+0x165 ole32.dll!CoRegisterChannelHook+0x538 kernel32.dll!GetModuleHandleA+0xdf

Answer (score 0):

This is the stack of your killed threads?  What is odd about the stack are these 2 calls:
AppSvr.dll!DllUnregisterServer+0x652 
OLEAUT32.dll!DllRegisterServer+0x5bf

Why would your application be registering or unregistering COM objects at runtime?

if AppSrv.dll is your application code, I would check the DllUnregisterServer and DllRegisterServer functions to make sure they don't have too much going on (that could hang the process or have a long loop).

The other API to focus on is calls to WS2_32.dll!recv+0x6f  ... those may be doing a lot of work or waiting on some network traffic.

Dave

Comment: None of it is our code.  It appears to be the third party biometric scanner software.  However, I believe the issue was caused by long running threads doing upload/download.  I moved the code that did that to a separate application pool and it solved this issue.